# Unable to locate elements using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am writing a script in Python using the modules 'requests' and 'BeautifulSoup' to scrape results from football matches found in the links from the following page:

https://www.premierleague.com/results?co=1&se=363&cl=-1

The task consists of two steps (taking the first match, Arsenal against Brighton, as an example):

1. Extract and navigate to the href "https://www.premierleague.com/match/59266" found in the element:
   div data-template-rendered data-href.
2. Navigate or to the "Stats"-tab and extracting the information found in the element:
   tbody class = "matchCentreStatsContainer".

I have already tried things like

```
page = requests.get("https://www.premierleague.com/match/59266")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "matchCentreStatsContainer"})
```

but I am not able to locate any of the elements in step 1) or 2) (empty list is returned).

Comment: what does `print(page)` show?  are you sure you getting any data from your request?

Comment: take a look at the bs docs to make sure you are searching for class correctly.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class
make sure your class actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "matchCentreStatsContainer"})
```

Use this

```
soup.findAll({"class" : "matchCentreStatsContainer"})
```

It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem is simply that you are looking for the wrong thing.  There is no `<div class="matchCentreStatsContainer">` on that page, that's a `<tbody>` so it doesn't match.  If you want the div, do:

```py
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="statsSection")
```

Otherwise search for the `tbody`s:

```py
soup.find_all("tbody", class_="matchCentreStatsContainer")
```

Incidentally the Right Way (TM) to match classes is with `class_`, which takes either a list or a string (for a single class).  This was added to bs4 a while back, but the old syntax is still floating around a lot.

Do note your first url as posted here is invalid: it needs a `http:` or `https:` before it.

### Update

Please note I would not parse this particularly file like this.  It has likely everything you already want as json.  I would just do:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(soup.find("div", class_="mcTabsContainer")["data-fixture"])
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Note that `data` is just a dictionary: I'm only using json.dumps at the end to pretty print it.

Comment: Thanks. How could I go about accesing the text found within the <p> nested in the <td> nested in <tr> within the <tbody> we've just located?

Comment: See the docs for `.next`  find and unique access.  In this case if a unique child you can likely just `.p`, else you can call find/find_all on the returned soup object (remember the outer find_all returned list)

Comment: Calling ```soup.find_all("tbody", class_="matchCentreStatsContainer")``` returns ```[<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"></tbody>]```, and using ```.p``` does not work. Is this assuming I already navigated to the "Stats"-tab?

Comment: I think you need to look more carefully at the html.  There isn't a <p> (or anything else) within the tbody you just found: it looks like this `<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer">                                                                                                                     
          </tbody>                                                                                                                                                      
         </table> `

You are looking at the *unrendered* html, aren't you, not what your browser is currently displaying?

Comment: Try doing `with open("test.html", "w") as f: f.write(soup.prettify())` and then opening test.html to see what's there

Comment: See also update; since I've actually had to look at the html, I thought I might as well tell you it already has json in it ;).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the data from the table on the page located in the

```<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer">``` 

is not found in the json data.